Subtlety of $\delta(x-y)$ and the arguments of test functions
Let $\Delta_n$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ converging to the tempered distribution $\delta(x-y)$ in the weak$^*$ topology. That is, for any $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \Delta_n(x,y)f(x,y) dxdy \to \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,x)dx \text{ as } n \to \infty.
\end{equation}
Now, I wonder if for any Schwartz function $g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, the following holds:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \Delta_n(x,y)g(x)dxdy \to \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)dx
$$
Heuristically, it seems plausible as $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(x-y)g(x)dxdy =  \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(x-y)g(x)dydx$ holds at least "formally".
However, $\delta(x-y)$ is supposed to be an element of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $g$ is a function of "single argument only". So, I am not sure if the heuristics can be justified.
Perhaps, is it possible to extend the domain of $\delta(x-y)$ to something larger than $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$? Could anyone please provide any clarification?
